# repeated number in string impala regex

Tags: regex, cloudera, impala

I need to filter rows with repeated numbers in some id field in a table. For that i use a regular expression

```
\b(\d)\1+\b
```

This is an example of the regex.

https://regex101.com/r/rJ7hJ6/7

But in impala this solution doesn't work. I tried

`select regexp_like('1111111111', '([0-9])\1+');` i this case return True

`select regexp_like('2222', '([0-9])\1+');` In this case return False

I think is because impala don't recognize `\1` operator so i added another backslash to the query to escape the operator

`select regexp_like('1111111111', '([0-9])\\1+');`

But when execute that i get a syntax error

```
Invalid regex expression: '([0-9])\1+'
```

Someone know whats is happened?? and how can fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: pretty confused between you first regex and second one, both are the same why is the first one returning true while the second one false?

Comment: I think is because does not´recognize  \1 operator and assume the number 1 is repeated one or more times in the string. This is why in the first example work and in the second one not

Comment: Try `$1` instead of `\1`

Comment: @Matt.G When i change \ for $ impala return False for both queries

Comment: Try `\b(?P<test>\d)(?P=test)+\b` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/px8tpZ/2)

Comment: @Matt.G when execute that i get this: Invalid regex expression: '(?P<test>d)(?P=test)+'

Comment: I think that on this page for [REGEXP_LIKE](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_like) there is a link to [the RE2 documentation](https://github.com/google/re2) where on [this page](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) it states `\1 backreference NOT SUPPORTED`